# DAO Testing, its not taking the testing or Id not sure what its wrong?

Tags: java, testing, dao

```
 public void createTimesheet_returns_timesheet_with_id_and_expected_values() {
        Timesheet createdTimesheet = sut.createTimesheet(testTimesheet);

        Assert.assertNotNull("createTimesheet returned null", createdTimesheet);
        Integer newId = createdTimesheet.getId();
        Assert.assertTrue("createProject failed to return a project with an id", newId > 0);

        testTimesheet.setId(newId);
        assertTimesheetsMatch("createProject returned project with wrong or partial data", testTimesheet, createdTimesheet);
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what is happening vs. what you expect should happen? It's not clear what the issue is, or how anyone can help.

Comment: im supposed to be creating a test for it but when i use the testTimesheet or getId it wont take it. it comes back with an error

Comment: This isn’t enough detail for anyone to provide helpful suggestions. What error? Specific error text, along with what inputs created that; along with what specific behavior was expected.